# UIButton inside of multiple UICollectionViewCells not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I have created a UICollectionView with cells called `baseCell`. Inside of those cells is another UICollectionView with cells called `subCell`. Inside of each `subCell` is a UIButton. The button has

Here is the code that sets up the button and its action:

```
let openOptionsButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CircleAdd"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(slideOverToOptions), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return button
}()

func slideOverToOptions() {
    print("This is working")
}

func setupViews(){ 
    addSubview(openOptionsButton)

            _ = openOptionsButton.anchor(topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 8, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 48, heightConstant: 48)
}
```

When I press the button, it does not print. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the issue. My problem was that I was accessing `self` inside of my button (in the `button.addTarget` line) with using a `let` declaration for the button. In order to access `self` inside my button, I needed to change `let` to `lazy var`. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the frame of your button or add it to a super view